How to Create a Chart with rounded bars in Android XML Using MPAndroidChart?

I want to create a chart in my Android app, and I’ve come across the MPAndroidChart library. It looks promising, but I couldn’t find clear documentation or examples showing how to define a chart directly in XML layout files. Specifically, I want to:
Add the chart in an XML layout.
Customize the chart properties like labels, colors, and data programmatically.
Understand best practices for integrating MPAndroidChart into my project.
Here are my questions:
Is it possible to add a chart (e.g., BarChart, LineChart) directly to an XML layout using MPAndroidChart?
If yes, what should the XML configuration look like, including essential attributes?
How can I programmatically populate and customize the chart after adding it in XML? For example, setting data, colors, animations, or legends.
Are there alternative approaches or libraries for creating highly customizable charts in Android if MPAndroidChart is not suitable for this?
I would greatly appreciate a step-by-step example or guidance for achieving this, including any relevant code snippets for both XML and Java/Kotlin. Thank you!

Have you taken a look at the library's documentation at all? https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/getting-started/
It should contain everything you want to do.

you can make your own custom render for chart and set it to your chart
CustomBarChartRender barChartRender = new CustomBarChartRender(barChart,barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler());
barChartRender.setRadius(20);
barChart.setRenderer(barChartRender);
